# How to push the first value of a list of arrays to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a nested array and want to push the first item from one of the arrays to state,

the Parent Array like this

```
"options": [
            {
                "id": 76,
                "label_en": "Disk Storage",
                "type": "text",
                "product_id": 20,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": 133,
                        "name_en": "32 GigByte",
                        "display_value": null,
                        "randam_key": "8596598ED", // this the target value I want to save
                        "option_id": 76
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 134,
                        "name_en": "16 GigByte",
                        "display_value": null,
                        "randam_key": "895454HG",
                        "option_id": 76
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
               .....
            }
    ]
```

every object from the "options - Parent" Array has a `values` array,
and every object of the `values` array has a `randam_key`

I want to save the first random key value from every object of the values array,
at the same time, i have a function that's store all values into a state to be like

```
//result
   bodyQuery =  {
        "product_id": 20,
        "values": {
            "randam_key1": "895454HG",
            "randam_key2": "FFJFOF568",
            "randam_key3": "FDVHFDVD566"
        }
    }

const getUpdatedPrice = (randam_key: string, handleKey: string) => {
    setBodyQuery((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      values: {
        ...prevState.values,
        [handleKey]: randam_key,
      },
    }));
  };
```

So what I tried is to get the keys *'Check the Live Code at the bottom'*, but i don't know how can I call `getUpdatedPrice()` to save the data as expected when the screen mounted.

the second case I have that saves the random keys after iterated the arrays and when I press to any item i call the `getUpdatedPrice()`
and this works very well but i need to do this behavior when screen mounted `useEffect()`!

**#Second Case - Work as expected**

```
{options.map((option) => {
     ....
     {option.values.map((value: valueOptionProp, index) => {
          // button
           onPress={()=> getUpdatedPrice(
                     value.randam_key,
                     'randam_key' + (options.indexOf(option) + 1),
                  );
             }
      })}
 })}
```

live code

```js
   
{/* let optionsArr=[]
options.map((option) => {
    optionsArr.push(option.values);
}
*/}
// the result of the above code is
optionsArr = [
    [
      {
        display_value: null,
        id: 133,
        name_en: '32 GigByte',
        option_id: 76,
        randam_key: '8596598ED',
      },
      {
        display_value: null,
        id: 134,
        name_en: '16 GigByte',
        option_id: 76,
        randam_key: '895454HG',
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        display_value: '#FFF',
        id: 135,
        name_en: 'ًWhite',
        option_id: 77,
        randam_key: 'FGFFDCF54',
      },
      {
        display_value: '#85FD',
        id: 136,
        name_en: 'Golden',
        option_id: 77,
        randam_key: 'FFJFOF568',
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        display_value: 'Url Image Here',
        id: 137,
        name_en: 'image 1',
        option_id: 78,
        randam_key: 'HGHVDF84585',
      },
      {
        display_value: 'Url Image Here',
        id: 138,
        name_en: 'Image 2',
        option_id: 78,
        randam_key: 'FDVHFDVD566',
      },
    ],
  ];
  
let first_randomKey = optionsArr.map(val=>val[0].randam_key);

console.log(first_randomKey);
```

**#Edit**

I try it like this and it works well!

> If there any other solutions please let me know!

```
useEffect(() => {
    let optionsArr: any[] = [];
    item.options.map((option) => {
      optionsArr.push(option.values);
    });
    let first_randomKey = optionsArr.map((val) => val[0].randam_key);
    let keys = first_randomKey.map((_itemKeys) => {
      getUpdatedPrice(
        _itemKeys,
        'randam_key' + (first_randomKey.indexOf(_itemKeys) + 1),
      );
    });
    Promise.all(keys).then(() => {
      isUpdated.current = true;
    });
  }, [item.options]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUpdated.current) {
      console.log('bodyQuery', bodyQuery);
    }
  }, [bodyQuery]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of inconsistencies and inefficiencies in your final code, mostly around your use of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

- `Array.prototype.map()` returns a new array, so declaring `optionsArr` and then using `map()` to push to it is redundant. You use it correctly in the next line however, when you assign `first_randomKey` by calling `map()` on the aforementioned `optionsArr`.
- In your final `map()` call you are manually finding the index of the current iterated `_itemsKeys` but this is unnecessary as `map()` provides this for you as the second parameter of the callback.  Again, elsewhere in your question you pass the index, but even then you aren't using it but manually finding the index.

The main inefficiency is that you using three `map()` calls for what could be achieved with one, here using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to access desired property, and leveraging the implicitly passed `index` parameter provided by `map()`.

```
const keys = item.options.map(({ values: [{ randam_key }] }, index) =>
  getUpdatedPrice(randam_key, 'randam_key' + (index + 1)));
```

or without destructuring

```
const keys = item.options.map((option, index) => {
  const randam_key = option.values[0].randam_key;
  return getUpdatedPrice(randam_key, 'randam_key' + (index + 1));
});
```

```js
const item = { "options": [{ id: 1, values: [{ id: 133, randam_key: "8596598ED" }, { id: 134, randam_key: "895454HG", }] }, { id: 1, values: [{ id: 135, randam_key: 'FGFFDCF54', }, { id: 136, randam_key: 'FFJFOF568', },] }, { id: 1, values: [{ id: 137, randam_key: 'HGHVDF84585', }, { id: 138, randam_key: 'FDVHFDVD566', },] }] }

const getUpdatedPrice = async (key, indexedKey) => {
  return [key, indexedKey]
}

const keys = item.options.map(({ values: [{ randam_key }] }, index) =>
  getUpdatedPrice(randam_key, 'randam_key' + (index + 1)));

Promise.all(keys).then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```